# Lua (.+) what does it mean?

Tags: lua, add-on

I found this code in the addon for wow, I wanted to rewrite it, but I came across a plus point, I thought it was interpolation... but no

`function Abar_spellhit(arg1)   a,b,spell=string.find (arg1, "Your (.+) hits")`

I looked for information on Google, looked for information about interpolation, nothing helped, if you tell me how I should have found it in Google, this is a special thank you to you.

p/s I'm bad at English and used a translator...

Comment: you should look at what `string.find` takes as arguments, it take a string and a pattern. `(.+)` is a capture sequence that captures all characters that appear between `Your ` and ` hits`